# Selenium 2 hub starts but throws 404 when trying to access console

Tags: java, grid, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-9.10

Starting hub on remoteservernode.com

```
moi@remote$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2.jar -role hub
Jun 18, 2011 4:32:25 PM org.openqa.grid.web.Hub loadGrid1Config
INFO: Did not find a Grid 1.0 configuration file.  Skipping Grid 1.0 setup.
Jun 18, 2011 4:32:25 PM org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer doStart
INFO: Version Jetty/5.1.x
Jun 18, 2011 4:32:25 PM org.openqa.jetty.util.FileResource <clinit>
INFO: Checking Resource aliases
Jun 18, 2011 4:32:26 PM org.openqa.jetty.util.Container start
INFO: Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.WebApplicationHandler@671381e7
Jun 18, 2011 4:32:26 PM org.openqa.jetty.util.Container start
INFO: Started WebApplicationContext[/,/]
Jun 18, 2011 4:32:26 PM org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener start
INFO: Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
Jun 18, 2011 4:32:26 PM org.openqa.jetty.util.Container start
INFO: Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@3dfeca64
Jun 18, 2011 4:34:06 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.RemoteProxy <init>
WARNING: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
Jun 18, 2011 4:34:06 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.RemoteProxy <init>
WARNING: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
Jun 18, 2011 4:34:06 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.RemoteProxy <init>
WARNING: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
Jun 18, 2011 4:34:06 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.RemoteProxy <init>
WARNING: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
Jun 18, 2011 4:34:06 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.RemoteProxy <init>
WARNING: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
Jun 18, 2011 4:34:06 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.RemoteProxy <init>
WARNING: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
```

Starting webdriver node (onanotherservernode.com).

```
me@server:~# java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2.jar -role webdriver -hub http://remoteservernode.com:4444/grid/register -port 5556
19:21:36.316 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 16.3-b01
19:21:36.318 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.31-14-server amd64
19:21:36.324 INFO - v2.0 [rc2], with Core v2.0 [rc2]
19:21:36.497 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:5556/wd/hub
19:21:36.498 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
19:21:36.499 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
19:21:36.500 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
19:21:36.501 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
19:22:37.977 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@21f8c6df
19:22:37.977 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
19:22:37.983 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5556
19:22:37.983 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@7d2a1e44
```

Navigating to console at http://remoteservernode.com:4444/console

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Not Found
RequestURI=/console

Powered by Jetty://
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too when trying Selenium 2.  There's a change, in that the console is now at /grid/console, e.g. http://remoteservernode.com:4444/grid/console

This is mentioned on http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Comment: You probably want to add a 2 on the end of that URL

Comment: Thanks for the note - fixed the URL to the selenium wiki article